# How to stop Expanded/Flexible Text widget from rendering partially hidden text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to fit the text widget into a card so that it uses as many lines as possible. However, when using the expanded widget on the text, the last line is rendered but only partially visible.

[this is how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J22r.png)

My code:

```
Card(
    child: Padding( // inner padding
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
        child: Column(
            children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                        'Lorem ipsum ....',
                        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                    ),
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                          size: 24,
                    )
                ),
                ]
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I get the same outcome when I use a high number as a maxlines prop. Unfortunately, I don't know beforehand how many lines there could be max as the content above is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Text widget into a `SingleChildScrollView` widget or use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package and decide for overflow.

Comment: Thanks Domain Name System. The card acts as a snippet, so I don't want to show the whole text. As for AutoSizeText, I tried it, but again I would need to set the maxlines. Setting an unrealistically high value gives the same outcome as in the screenshot.